# TVOS getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable when calling SWIFT function

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

I am trying to playback youtube videos with tvml on my appleTV. It is based on:
https://gist.github.com/nickv2002/b7bb28cdccc000bdb910

The first time I start it, it is working, but after I play around (leaving the app), I get:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: playYTblock
```

After rebooting/exit(0)ing the app the ATV it is working again... it seems, the context between the app<>tvjs is lost - anyone with ideas?

Here is my code:

```
in AppDelegate.swift
let playerVC = YTPlayerViewController()

in the application function:
playerVC.createPlayYT( appController! )

in presenter.js
if (youtubeUrl && (event.type === "play")) {
        playYTblock(youtubeUrl);
    }

in the template.xml.js
<listItemLockup youtubeUrl="H4O6oEaIDrs">
```

btw has anyone an idea why the event.type === select is fired right after loading the template (without clicking on my side)

Answer (score -1):

Can't answer about that exact problem but,

Here is what i'm using is to play youtube video on tvos :

pod "AKYoutubeParser"

A parser to retrieve the actual youtube video urls.
And the video playback is handled by apple core stuff (AVFoundation, AVKit)

you can delete all the hud part if you don't use it.

```
import AKYoutubeParser
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

func displayTrailer(trailer: String) {
    AKYoutubeParser.h264Streams(trailer) { [weak self] streams, error in
        if let s = streams, v = AKYoutubeParser.getBestQuality(s) {
            let playerVC = AVPlayerViewController()
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVAsset(URL: v.url))
            let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            playerVC.player = videoPlayer
            self?.presentViewController(playerVC, animated: true) {
                playerVC.player?.play()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the player but the JSContext. The call to the JS-Function which should start the Swiftcode to play the video is not found once the App entered the background and becomes active again

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is a tool recommendation.